# How do programs run in background?

Tags: malware

When coming across malicious Windows executable files, I noticed that some `.exe` files are able to run without opening a window of any kind. However,  when running executables written in languages like C or C++, they always open up a console window at the very least.

**How are malicious Windows executables able to run without having a window or showing up in the taskbar?**

Is it a certain language or API that allows them to do this?

Comment: Job control. You use "&" at the end of the command on Linux. For Windows see this related thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/121979/tools-to-run-a-background-process-command-line-in-windows/714560

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways. The simplest is that they can run as a Windows subsystem process (instead of a Console subsystem - i.e. command-line one), and just not bother to ever create and show a window. They can run as a service process, or as a child of a service process (via injection into the service); those don't show UI. They can run on a different desktop (though there's no reason to do this, unless they want to show a window but don't want other processes to see that window). There's probably many others.